# Google Maps, how to save polylines lat/lng as data array for heatmap visualisation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to save a usermade polyline path as a data array for heatmap visualisation on a button click.

Currently I'm trying to generate the heatmap with a pre-set data and it happens to give the error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined at toggleHeatmap

Is anyone able to provide a solution which :
1 - make the heatmap display atleast with the preset data.
2 - extracts the data from the usermade polylines into the data array.

Many thanks in advance!

```
   <script>

    var poly;
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var heatmap;


    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {lat: 60.1675, lng: 24.9311},
            zoomControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true
        });

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        poly.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event
        map.addListener('click', addLatLng);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: getPoints(),
            map: map
        });
    }


    function toggleHeatmap() {

        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
    }

    function getPoints() {
        return [
            new google.maps.LatLng(60.1675, 24.9211),
            new google.maps.LatLng(60.1675, 24.9212),
            new google.maps.LatLng(60.1675, 24.9213)
        ]
    }


    // Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
    function addLatLng(event) {
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(event.latLng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            title: '#' + path.getLength(),
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
    function setMapOnAll(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }

    // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
    function clearMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(null);
    }

    // Shows any markers currently in the array.
    function showMarkers() {
        setMapOnAll(map);
    }

    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
    function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
        markers = [];
    }

    //Function to remove lines
    function removeLine() {
        var path = poly.getPath();
        path.clear();

    }

    function clearPath() {
        removeLine();
        clearMarkers();
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the issue was due to the API script. Needed to add "&libraries=visualization" after the API key as following :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization">
</script>
```